# Docker networking setup that is private and proxied

Tags: networking, firewall, docker

[image: Desired schema]

Above is a layout of the desired network. I am struggling with getting it just right. **The internal link from the router is not relevant for this problem**.

**Requirements:**

1. The only container directly exposed to the public, should be the proxy.
2. All containers can communicate with eachother, preferrably via host name (see user-defined docker network).
3. Some services such as Portainer require internet access (outgoing) to retrieve some data from their servers but should otherwise not be directly accessible.
4. The host may be allowed to access container services directly, but only from the host itself, not externally.

**What I have achieved so far:**

1. The proxy correctly proxies the desired containers to the outside.
2. All containers can communicate with eachother and their IP can be resolved via service name.

**Problems:**

1. All containers are still accessible directly, without using the proxy (by using their exposed ports)
2. If they are not in a bridge network they don't have internet, but if they are, they are accessible directly.

I believe 3 networks are necessary:

1. An internal network for the containers themselves
2. A network that has internet (but somehow does not expose any ports)
3. A network that will be used by the proxy that gets exposed to the public

I am configuring everything via Portainer, and the docker host is using Firewalld. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You're ready to move up to Kubernetes, I think.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is Kubernetes not a wrapper for Docker? How does it differ in these networks?

Comment: Kubernetes is a mostly complete container orchestration solution. In particular for your case, it has advanced networking functionality which would allow you to isolate containers from each other and from the Internet.

Comment: It's a little strange that this does not work for Docker. It seems like a common use case. Or perhaps another server (before the docker host) takes care of the isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so after revisiting this issue, I was reading a cheatsheet for Docker, and realized you can bind to an interface. By default, if no interface is specified, it binds to `0.0.0.0`, but by specifying, for example `127.0.0.1:80:80` means only the docker host will be able to access the container on port 80.

This way, I specified my private network (192.168.1.0/24) as the interface to bind to for all exposed ports of my docker containers (so I can access directly from within my network) and only the Caddy proxy I bound to `0.0.0.0`. Now this is behaving like I want and no special setup was needed.

Additionally I linked all containers together to the same user-defined network called `internal` in which I set **restrict external access** to `true`. This way, the containers can talk to eachother, can be resolved by container name and cannot be accessed by anything but my private network. All services from all containers are exposed to the public only by the reverse proxy.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `docker-compose.yml` file that you got things working with?

Comment: Can you post your configuration? It seem to me that your proxy is configured outside of the `internal` network and container in the `internal` network communicate with proxy using `host` interface (proxy is bound on `0.0.0.0` on that interface). That works, but ultimately what I am looking is for cross-network peering, so my proxy can be in the `external` network, where as other containers would remain in `internal`.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue You can add your proxy to both your external network and internal network. Acting as some kind of bridge to "cross the gap". Your proxy will receive connections from your external network, and will be able to access the containers in the internal network by name.

Comment: This is what I've done. My inbound proxy is NginX, my outbound proxy is Squid. Application containers are in the internal network, whereas these proxies are in both internal and external network. Here is my config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729953/docker-compose-restrict-internet-access-allow-egress-only-through-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Put all containers in an Docker Overlay network. This way they will communicate with each other but you won't be able to otherwise connect to any of them. Setup the Proxy as an Ingress Docker Service. By default the containers will also have access to connect to the Internet.

If you want only SOME containers to access the Internet, disable IP masquerading for that Overlay network and:

a. Create another overlay network with ICC disabled and masquerading enabled, attaching only the containers needing access to Internet to that network.

b. Setup a proxy container, like Squid, and give it Internet access via the default Bridge network of Docker, where you permit IP Masquerading.

c. A combination of a) and b).